# lsp client failing to attach as part of autocmd

Tags: neovim, lsp

I'm using the `nvim-lspconfig` plugin to set up *sh, lua, and python LSPs. If I have the setup function at the 'top level' of my init.lua, the servers attach as expected. However, I'd like the lsp servers to only attempt to connect for the appropriate files, rather than attempting the connection every time. To do that, I'm attempting to wrap the setup functions in an autocmd, but when I put it there, the servers won't attach.

Example snippet from init.lua that *does work*:

```
require("lspconfig").sumneko_lua.setup(sumneko_settings)
```

With the above in my init.lua, after opening a lua file, I can run `:LspInfo` and see that the lua language server has attached.

[image: screenshot of successfully attached lua language server]

This, however, does *not* work:

```
local lua_lsp_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("lua_lsp", {clear = true})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
  pattern = {"lua"},
  callback = function()
    require("lspconfig").sumneko_lua.setup(sumneko_settings)
  end,
  group = lua_lsp_group
}
```

Running `:LspInfo` with this configuration shows no server attached, but does show that the `filetype` has been set appropriately to `lua`.

[image: screenshot of failed lua language server attach]

In the failed attempt you can see that it's failing to detect the root directory, but I am using identical settings for both examples.

```
local runtime_path = vim.split(package.path, ";")
table.insert(runtime_path, "lua/?.lua")
table.insert(runtime_path, "lua/?/init.lua")

local sumneko_settings = {
  on_attach = attach_func,
  settings = {
    Lua = {
      runtime = {
        version = "LuaJIT",
        path = runtime_path,
      },
      diagnostics = {
        globals = {"vim"}
      },
      workspace = {
        library = api.nvim_get_runtime_file("", true),
       },
      telemetry = {enable = false},
    },
  },
}
```

Is there something about the way autocommands work that prevents my runtime path adjustments from taking effect appropriately? I don't think the runtime path is the real problem though, because I experience the same problem with pyright and bashls when I try to contain the setup function for those within an autocommand group.

For additional context, I am also using the Scala language server `nvim-metals` and having no issues activating it with an autocommand, so I know this *should* work. (Though `nvim-metals` does have its own setup for attaching the language server to neovim, so I am not using the `nvim-lspconfig` plugin for that setup.)

```
local nvim_metals_group = api.nvim_create_augroup("nvim-metals", {clear = true})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("FileType", {
  pattern = {"scala", "sbt"},
  callback = function()
    require("metals").initialize_or_attach(metals_config)
  end,
  group = nvim_metals_group,
})
```

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect the following difference : metals probably creates or attaches to the lsp when called, whereas the native lspconfig probably creates its own autocommands. Creating autocommands during an autocommand is obviously going to be too late, as they won’t fire until the next file that matches (and if that triggers lspconfig again, and if lspconfig wipes its group before creating it, there’s a chance it won’t work at all even for the next file). Does it work on the second file if you edit one file (say Python) and then edit a second, different Python file ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice - yes, for the first opened buffer, `pyright` doesn't attach, but then editing a second buffer it will attach. (Interestingly enough, after it attaches to the second buffer, it will go back and attach a language server instance to the first buffer.) 

Using the setup where I _don't_ define my own augroup, I am seeing strange behavior with the lua and *sh lsp where whenever I source my config it attaches an additional instance of the language server, but not seeing that in python. So perhaps the augroups created by the plugin aren't clearing themselves?

Comment: Could be. Sounds like using lspconfig directly is still the way to go; you might want to avoid executing again when « reloading » though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @D. Ben Knoble for the suggestion to look into whether the config plugin I was using was already creating the autocommands.

That does appear to be the case - https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/configs.lua#L67.

So the 'answer' here is to use the `nvim-lspconfig` plugin as explained in the documentation and not try to wrap the setup functions in their own autocommands/groups.